# Testing a method which requires use of other methods of same class in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

Here is the part of the data structure:

```
public class SLList {

  public class IntNode {
      public int item;
      public IntNode next;

      public IntNode(int item, IntNode next){
          this.item = item;
          this.next = next;
      }
  }

  private IntNode first;

  public SLList(int x){
      this.first = new IntNode(x, null);
  }

  public void addFirst(int n){
      first = new IntNode(n, first);
  }

  public int getFirst(){
      return first.item;
  }
}
```

Now, I need to test the two methods, addFirst() and getFirst(). I wrote the code as:

```
public class SLListTest {

@Test
public void addFirst() {
    SLList s = new SLList(10);
    s.addFirst(5);
    Assert.assertEquals(5, s.getFirst());
}

@Test
public void getFirst() {
    SLList s = new SLList(10);
    s.addFirst(5);
    Assert.assertEquals(5, s.getFirst());
}
}
```

Now, I see a problem here, the call to other functions in the test. For example, test to addFirst() depends on getting getFirst() right and similar thing with getFirst(). How do I write the test to solve this problem? For example what if both of my methods are wrong but due to the dependency, test cases pass?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to solve.

Rename your test (e.g. add test prefix - `testAddFirst()`)

With best regards, Fr0z3Nn

Comment: I don't think it will solve the problem I am asking. I am calling s.addFirst(x), which won't change if I rename my test method from addFirst() to testAddFirst().